# In SSRS 2008, how do I show the labels and values of a multi-value parameter together in a text box?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

This seems like it should be trivial, but I just can't seem to find the correct expression or work it out myself.

Using Microsoft SQL server report builder SSRS, I have a multi-value parameter named "Diagnoses", with the following properties:

[image: Diagnoses properties 1]

[image: Diagnoses properties 2]

In a text box in my report, I would like to list the labels the user has selected, along with their corresponding values.  For example if the user selected "Breast" and "Lung", you would see something like this:

```
You have selected the following site groups / diagnosis codes:

Site Group       Diagnosis Codes

Breast           (List of breast codes)

Lung             (List of lung codes)
```

Are there any expression gurus out there who could help me? Maybe the solution is to use a Tablix?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result you want with 3 textboxes (*optional: use rectangle for container*), follow the layout I have below:

[image: textbox layout]

Use this in the Expr in **Site Group**:

```
=JOIN(Parameters!Diagnoses.Label, vbcrlf)
```

Use this in the Expr in **Diagnosis Codes**:

```
=JOIN(Parameters!Diagnoses.Value, vbcrlf)
```

If you want your labels to repeat across pages, I'd recommend putting them inside the report header section.